# How to make a global accessible structure in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to add a new functionality to Linux Kernel. In order to implement it I need to add a structure that can be accessed from another parts of the kernel by name.

How can I do it?

Comment: It might be a bad idea. For modularity reasons you might prefer providing functions (perhaps inlined ones) to give this functionality. A huge program with hundreds of global data is messy, so the community might dislike your idea.... and prefer a clean API defined by functions. (Also, a global data cannot be accessed in the kernel without care, because of locking, interrupts, etc...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, I thought about it, but actually I have no idea how to implement it. If you can help, I would like to see it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: So I gave a reply below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a kernel expert, but I would suggest avoiding having a globally visible symbol, and provide a function-based API (perhaps with some inlined functions, for those few who are performance critical).

I would suggest defining a set of functions only. Also, I'm not sure that giving a global data is a good idea -they are probably synchronization issues, especially on multi-core machines [most systems have at least 2 cores today]. So you probably better define a set of function interfaces, document them well (at least with good comments), and avoid global data.

I would also suggest to take inspiration from some part (or sub-system) of the kernel which might be similar to what you want to achieve. I also suggest to take advice from the kernel community, even early during the design phase, of your work (in particular, make your code publicly available even before it is working, to enable comments).

Good luck. It would be nice to understand what kind of sub-system or functionality are you aiming to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Decaring your structure in module.h will lead to compilation of all the modules in kernel. Better choose a header file in your local directory or create a new header defining your structure in the local dir. Since you said your component will be part of kernel, so declare the structure variable in a c file and use it where ever you want with extern modifier. This will not require exporting of sysmbol. It will something like below:

```
kernel/test.h:  
struct test {
     char name[10][20];
};

kernel/workqueue.c:
struct test *test_list;
some_fun()
{
      test_list = kmalloc(sizeof(struct test) * 2, GFP_KERNEL);
}

kernel/softirq.c:
extern struct test *test_list;
printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", test_list[0].name[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `EXPORT_SYMBOL` to export your structure variable. it will be seen in the whole kernel code and  modules

Comment: Alex will want to put the header defining it somewhere under the top-level include directory also.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure whether I understood your question.  As per my understanding,

You are trying to define a new user-defined structure and wants to use them in necessary places. and also looking for a common place where to define it. right??

All the kernel modules should include `linux/module.h`. You can add your structure here. I hope this will be accessible in all the modules.

Comment: It will not be included as module - it will be a part of kernel.

Comment: yes you can.... say you are trying to use that struct in a Ethernet driver. That Ethernet driver also includes `module.h`. so you have access to your struct type..